# Usage of verb according to subject

Tags: grammar, british-english, subcontinental-english

Is the given sentence gramatically correct? I am a beginner in english.

Being born in the christian faith, I has often to go to the church.

Comment: Hello, 261. 'christian' should be 'Christian', 'has' should be 'had' or have', 'to the church' is perhaps better written 'to church', and 'Being born in[to] the Christian faith' is probably contentious (Christians believe that all people are born sinners, and need to become Christians by repentance and faith in Christ [from the human perspective: He's done the rest]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say “Being born to the Christian faith, I often have to go to Church.”

“To” vs “in” isn’t a very important distinction, but it does make a difference. Someone would be born “in” a hospital, but they’d be born “to” a happy home. “In” usually talks about the birth itself, while “to” usually talks about the life surrounding that birth. At least that’s how I see it.

“Christian” should be capitalised as it is a proper name, just like the names of people or locations. In general, all religious groups (Christianity, Islam, Catholic etc.) should be capitalized.

“I has often to go to the church” is incorrect in a few ways:

Firstly, the word “has/have” should depend on the tense, and the person it refers to. In this case, you are referring to “I” (first person), and to “have to” in the present tense, so you should use “have”.

In English, it can be difficult to place the time phrase correctly, because depending on the word choice, the sentence structure could change. In some cases, many different structures would be just as valid - “Sometimes, I hate English”, “I sometimes hate English”, and “I hate English sometimes” all mean the exact same thing, for example.

For “often”, it usually goes right in front of the ‘main’ verb - in this case “have”. So we have “I often have to go” so far.

“Church” in this sentence doesn’t refer to a church building. Instead it’s talking about Church, the religious group inside that building. In this case, we don’t need to call it “the” church, but we do need to capitalize the word “Church” since it’s a religious group.

So in the end, we’re left with “Being born to the Christian faith, I often have to go to Church.”